# How do I schedule a task to run every hour indefinitely on Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

I am moving a scheduled task from a Windows 7 machine to a Windows Server 2003 machine.

On Windows 7 I can configure my task to run every hour indefinitely by setting up a custom trigger like so:

[image: MyTask7]

On Windows Server 2003, I assume I need to use the advanced schedule options, and I have got this far:

[image: MyTask2003]

Whether I choose duration or time, my task seems to have an expiry date, how do I get this to run indefinitely? The only thing I can think of at the minute is to setup 24 schedules for my task, one for each hour but there has to be a more elegant way.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need the task to run infinitely just long enough that you never have to worry about it again...set the end date 50 years into the future. It shouldn't really matter either way

Comment: -1 because IMHO the question is not about the `End Date`, but rather the `Until` value. This answer does not (AFAICT) explain what value to use for `Time` or `Duration` in order to ensure that the task repeats throughout the day.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I've got one of those tasks set up.  (Every three hours instead of one, but you should get the gist.)

[image]

Task runs daily, repeats every x hours for... all day.

Comment: Any reason you chose `23:59` instead of `24:00` for the Duration? You state that yours works, so I'm blindly going to copy it, but I wonder if there's any downside to just using `24 hours`.